# Why will my Nginx docker container not start when the --restart switch is specified

Tags: nginx, docker, restart

I am running Nginx on Ubuntu 14.04 as a reverse proxy to my .NET Core Web APIs.  It works well, starting with the command line:

```
docker run --name=nginx -d -v /mercury/config/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d -v /mercury/logs/nginx:/var/log/nginx -p0.0.0.0:443:443 -t docker-registry.public-upstream.gray.net/nginx
```

I want the container to restart if it crashes or the server is restarted, which (according to the documentation) can be achieved by adding `--restart=unless-stopped` to the command line.

However, when I do this, I get the error:

`docker: Error response from daemon: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "exec: \"--restart=unless-stopped\": executable file not found in $PATH".`

I'm not sure where to go from here - what executable file is it looking for, since I'm running a container?  Why does this error occur with the flag, but docker can start the container fine without it?

I've dug around one Google, but have not been able to find a solution.  There are a fair number of similar questions but few solutions and none which seem to apply in my case.

**Edit:**
I should mention that in my case this is specific to nginx - my own containers run fine with the `--restart` switch specified.

Comment: have you tried with `--restart=always` ?

Comment: Yes, it gives the same error.  Seems to me something to do with dockers internal setup of a restart monitor, but it must ultimately be configuration related.

Comment: this will work  - docker run --name=nginx -d -v /mercury/config/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d -v /mercury/logs/nginx:/var/log/nginx -p0.0.0.0:443:443 -t nginx

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much the command line which works as I specified (internally we have a proxy to the docker hub, that's the only difference).  My question is about how to get the `--restart` command line switch working.  As soon as I add that, the error I mentioned is thrown.

Comment: Can you post `docker run` command (with the restart policy) that is giving you the error?

Comment: `docker run --name=nginx -d -v /mercury/config/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d -v /mercury/logs/nginx:/var/log/nginx -p0.0.0.0:443:443 -t nginx --restart=unless-stopped`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

`docker run --name=nginx --restart unless-stopped -d -v /mercury/config/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d -v /mercury/logs/nginx:/var/log/nginx -p0.0.0.0:443:443 -t docker-registry.public-upstream.gray.net/nginx`

Comment: It appears that the position of the --restart option is important, this works, thanks!  I would have expected a meaningful error :-)